# could not direct to an action class from jsp display tag - Struts2

Tags: struts2, displaytag

I have to read `acct_code` value dynamically and when clicked the `acct_code` hyperlink, a java class's method should be triggered. I have written like below.

```jsp
<display:column property="acct_code" 
                title="Account Identifier" 
                sortable="true"
                href="accRec.do?acct_code=<s:property value=acct_code/>"/>
```

struts.xml

```xml
<action name="accRec.do" class="util.TestAccount" method="execute_details">
   <result name="success">/accountrecord.jsp</result>
</action>
```

but the problem is, when I inspect element, i cannot see the `acct_code` value. So, could not propagate to java class.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: my question is, I am not able to read acct_code value dynamically and go to the action class TestAccount.
Am I missing something over there in code ?

Comment: This are two different questions neither of them are working for you.

Comment: Yes, neither of them is working.. I have tried hard coding acct_code value and click on the hyperlink, then it displays "Error 404: SRVE0190E: File not found: /accRec.do "
corresponding java file and the method are there in the specified class path.

Comment: The file doesn't have required parts of the code and it doesn't go to the action.

Comment: which file?
In,JSP page,Im able to display acct_code from DB , and it is listed on UI..
the same variable acct_code, Im trying to passing as a query string in the href attribute in display tag.. but it is not retrievable..

Comment: If you are able to desplay it in the UI then you should be able to store it to the BD. No matter what variable is stored to but it passed BD for conversion and if not the conversion fails the value could be seen via the datasource editor.

Comment: I am able to resolve one problem. by removing .do in struts.xml and in href attribute of jsp.
I am able to navigate to next jsp by hardcoding the acct_code value.
the only problem remaining is failed to retrieve dynamic acct_code value

Comment: You can retrieve it in any other ways show the code that is related to the problem. Without code is impossible to help.